# Expression templates with a hierarchy defined on the nodes in the syntax tree

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, expression-templates

I found an excellent explanation of expression templates [here](http://www.angelikalanger.com/Articles/Cuj/ExpressionTemplates/ExpressionTemplates.htm#Moving%20on%20to%20Expression%20Templates). In the article, we find a basic expression template implementation for arithmetic, as follows (slightly adapted):

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T>
struct plus {
    T operator()(const T a, const T b) const { return a + b; }
};

template <class ExprT>
struct exprTraits {
    typedef ExprT expr_type;
};

template <class ExprT1, class ExprT2, class BinOp>
class BinaryExpr {
   public:
    BinaryExpr(ExprT1 e1, ExprT2 e2, BinOp op = BinOp()) : _expr1(e1), _expr2(e2), _op(op) {}
    double eval() const { return _op(_expr1.eval(), _expr2.eval()); }

   private:
    typename exprTraits<ExprT1>::expr_type _expr1;
    typename exprTraits<ExprT2>::expr_type _expr2;
    BinOp _op;
};

class Literal {
   public:
    Literal(const double v) : _val(v) {}
    double eval() const { return _val; }

   private:
    const double _val;
};

template <>
struct exprTraits<double> {
    typedef Literal expr_type;
};

class Variable {
   public:
    Variable(double& v) : _val(v) {}
    double eval() const { return _val; }

    void operator+=(double x) { _val += x; }

   private:
    double& _val;
};

class SpecialVariable : public Variable {
   public:
    SpecialVariable(double& v) : Variable{v} {};
    double eval() const { return -1000.0; }
};

template <class ExprT1, class ExprT2>
BinaryExpr<ExprT1, ExprT2, plus<double>> operator+(ExprT1 e1, ExprT2 e2) {
    return BinaryExpr<ExprT1, ExprT2, plus<double>>(e1, e2);
}
```

There are three type of nodes, `Literal`, `Variable` and `SpecialVariable` which is a subclass of the latter. The traits are there to allow for built-in types like `double` in the expressions without wrapping them with `Literal`.

Now, suppose I want to do something particular when I add a `double` and a `Variable` and plus-assign it to a `Variable`. I add following member function to `Variable`:

```
void operator+=(BinaryExpr<double, Variable, plus<double>> expr) { _val += 1000.0; }
```

and write a little test program:

```
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) {
    double xd = 2.0, yd = 5.0;
    Variable x{xd};
    SpecialVariable y{yd};
    x += 3.0 + y;
    std::cout << "result : " << std::to_string(x.eval()) << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This, however, only works with `Variable`s and not `SpecialVariable`s, i.e. I get following compiler error:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+=’ (operand types are ‘Variable’ and ‘BinaryExpr<double, SpecialVariable, plus<double> >’) x += 3.0 + y;
note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘BinaryExpr<double, SpecialVariable, plus<double> >’ to ‘BinaryExpr<double, Variable, plus<double> >’
```

which is completely reasonable since template classes do not necessarily have a relation if their template arguments have one.

**Question**: how can I write one `operator+=` that accepts expression templates with types **and** possibly their subtypes? I've not seen an expression template tutorial that addresses this particular problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Question: how can I write one `operator+=` that accepts expression templates with types and possibly their subtypes?

Using `std::is_base_of` and SFINAE

```
template <typename V>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Variable, V>>
   operator+= (BinaryExpr<double, V, plus<double>> expr)
 { _val += 1000.0; }
```

The preceding code compile in C++17.

If you're using C++14 you have to use

```
std::is_base_of<Variable, V>::value
```

instead of

```
std::is_base_of_v<Variable, V>
```

If you're using C++11 you have to use

```
typename std::enable_if<std::is_base_of<Variable, V>::value>::type
```

instead of

```
std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of_v<Variable, V>>
```

Comment: When I use your C++14 alternative, I get the following `error: dependent-name ‘std::is_base_of<Variable, V>::type’ is parsed as a non-type, but instantiation yields a type` and
`note: say ‘typename std::is_base_of<Variable, V>::type’ if a type is meant` (with `g++-7.4.0` and either of the above standards)

Comment: ^ never mind, I made a mistake (`::type` vs `::value` after `is_base_of`)